# How can I exclude certain elements from css property that has been applied to their parent without using the style attribute

Tags: html, css

my table is auto generated so I can't give it classes. All i can do is white general css like the following

```
td{white-space:nowrap}
a{white-space:normal}
```

How can I give the `text1` normal white-space but nowrap for text 2 and text 3?

```
<tr>
<td>
<a href=""...>text 1</a>
</td>
<td>
text 2
</td>
<td>
text3
</td
</tr>
```

Comment: What you've written above looks like it should work (apart from the missing > at the end of the last "</td", but I presume that is just in the example code above).  Are you sure there aren't other CSS declarations that are affecting things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your link is always on first cell of your row you could solve with

```
tr td:first-child { white-space : nowrap }
a { white-space : normal }
```

(I have no other clues for different solutions)

Comment: a variation of this worked. `td{white-space:nowrap;} td:first-child{white-space:normal;}` thanks

Answer (score 2):

put

```
td { white-space:nowrap; }
td a { white-space:normal; }
```

remember to have the

```
td a {..}
```

after

```
td {..}
```

Comment: +1 except the order of `td a` and `td` do not matter here. `td a` is more specific then `td` so will be applied whether it is written first or last.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this way using pseudo elements in css.

table tr td a{white-space : normal }
table tr td + td a{white-space :normal; }